# JavaFX TableView wrapped text selected row text color

Tags: css, javafx, tableview, word-wrap

I used Stackoverflow for wrapping the text in a table cell. But when I focus on a table row, the text color does not change anymore. I tried everything.

This is what I have now in my Controller:

```
       colWie.setCellFactory(column -> {
        return new TableCell<DraaiboekActie, String>() {
            private Text text;

            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!isEmpty()) {
                    text = new Text(item);
                    text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(colWie.widthProperty());
                    text.getStyleClass().add("coltext");
                    setGraphic(text);
                    }
               }
           };
       });
```

And this is what I have in my css :

```
.coltext {
-fx-fill: white;
}

.coltext:focused:selected:filled{
-fx-fill: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like

```css
.table-cell .coltext {
    -fx-fill: white ;
}

.table-cell:focused:filled:selected .coltext {
    -fx-fill: black ;
}
```

(I'm assuming `coltext` and `draaiboektext` are supposed to be the same thing.)